# Javascript import module to index.html not running due to errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a module to my index.html file.

Here is the code:

```
// Index.html:

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>

</head>

<body>

<div></div>

  <script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    import { addTextToBody } from 'module.js';

    addTextToBody('some text here');

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the js:

```
export function addTextToBody(text) {

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(div);

}
```

I am getting these errors:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { - Line 18

Access to Script at 'module.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use `<script type="module">` even for the inline script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. `module.js` should be `./module.js`
2. You don't need to import the module at the beginning of the page (but you can).
3. Using `import` requires the script to be of type `module` not just the imported script.
4. You should place modules imports in `<head>` (at the very beginning).

The following example works (I cut out unessential parts):

```
<!-- index.html -->
<meta charset="utf-8">

<script type="module">
  import { addTextToBody } from './module.js';

  addTextToBody('some text here');
</script>
```

```
// module.js
export function addTextToBody(text) {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.textContent = text;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

The code provided above will work with Firefox, but not with Chrome. It appears you are using Chrome (I assume that from your error message). Chrome strictly forbids access to resources with the `file://` protocol. There are a handful solutions:

1. Host your code with a webserver (e.g. [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/)).
2. Use a different webbrowser (e.g. [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/)).
3. Disable web security altogether, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177718/8746648).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import { addTextToBody } from './module.js';
```

Comment: Where is the module located with regards to index.html?

Comment: Both files are in the same folder. I the root of the folder so same level